# Can anything be the logical consequence of an always false statement? For eg: $p \wedge \neg p$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$p \wedge \neg p$ is never true, does that mean that any statement can be it's logical consequence?

Comment: What's your definition of logical consequence?

Comment: You might be interested in the principle of explosion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion

Comment: Briefly, Yes. *false* implies anything.

Comment: Yes,and that is why $\neg (p\land \neg p)$. Let $ s=p\land \neg p.$ Now if $ \neg s$ then  we have $\neg s$,but if $s$ then $s\to \neg s$ so again we have $\neg s.$

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by logical consequence, if you mean to ask if  $p\wedge \neg p\models r$ for every formula $r$, then yes, as, by the deduction theorem, we have that this is equivalent to $\models (p\wedge  \neg p)\rightarrow r$, which is true: that formula is in fact a tautology (check with truth tables).

Answer (score 0):

If the premise is false, the conclusion is always true.